# How to enable root login with password authentication on AWS ec2 Ubuntu instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I edited sshd_config file and set

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

After that, I created a new user

```
adduser John
```

Granted root priviledges

```
usermod -aG sudo John
```

After that, I connected using sFTP client and tried to transfer a file. However server sent error message "Permission denied"

I rebooted the server after modification.

Comment: I think you are not using any key pairs/private keys to connect to the instance. let us more about if you set default password for user John. check /etc/passwd. also, check ec2 instance startup log files from ec2 console. and I hope you restarted ssh daemon or reloaded it after modifications. use ssh first to see if that works, then use sFTP, this is easier to debug.

Comment: @Sam Thanks for your comment. I want to connect to instance without keys. That's why, I created a new user John & set password for it. Yes, I restarted ssh daemon after modifications. I will check with ssh to see if works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  PubkeyAuthentication No in  /etc/ssh/sshd_config file